# How to iterate through a list using a stepper variable in Python?

Tags: python, variables, for-loop, iteration

I am trying to write a function that returns a hangman style output given an input of guessed characters and a secret to be guessed. I start by making a new list `a`set to `-` as many times as the length of the secret. I then iterate through this variable and test if `a[stepper] == letter` where `letter` is the walker as we loop through.

Currently to keep track of this stepper I am using this code

```
a = ["-"] * len(secret) 
for curr in guessed:
    letter_count = 0  # Stepper
    for letter in secret:
        if curr == letter:
            a[letter_count] = curr
        letter_count += 1
```

Is there a built in functionality for `letter_count` as I am using here?

Comment: What is `a`? not the best variable name...

Comment: @DeepSpace `a` is a list of dashes of set length

Comment: If `a == '-'*len(secret)`, when is `curr` going to be anything but `-`?

Comment: @PatrickHaugh Thanks for the point, I copied my code wrong I iterate through `guessed` not `a`

Comment: You can't change characters in a string in situ, you have to build a new one.  `''.join([letter if letter in guessed else '-' for letter in secret])`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [`enumerate()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#enumerate) builtin function like this:

```
a = ['-'] * len(secret)
for curr in guessed:
    for i, letter in enumerate(secret):
        if curr == letter:
            a[i] = curr
```

Comment: Variable `a` must be a `list` or `dict`. If it is a `list` it must have the same length as `secret`.

Comment: a is a list the same length as secret

Comment: You are creating a new `a` list?

Comment: Yes, in the beginning of the function `a` is defined by a loop which makes it a list of dashes the same length as the secret.

Comment: @Travis I defined list `a` here too for completeness.

Answer (score 3):

You could create the displayed word dynamically with [`join`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.join) and a comprehension. The guesses are stored in a [`set`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/sets.html) and a ternary operator checks if the letter or `-` should be displayed:

```
>>> word = "hangman"
>>> guessed = set()
>>> ''.join(letter if letter in guessed else '-' for letter in word)
'-------'
>>> guessed.add('a')
>>> ''.join(letter if letter in guessed else '-' for letter in word)
'-a---a-'
>>> guessed.add('m')
>>> ''.join(letter if letter in guessed else '-' for letter in word)
'-a--ma-'
>>> guessed.add('e')
>>> ''.join(letter if letter in guessed else '-' for letter in word)
'-a--ma-'
>>> guessed.add('n')
>>> ''.join(letter if letter in guessed else '-' for letter in word)
'-an-man'
```